# MSSQL get list of years from multiple dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to get a list of years from multiple dates in my table. Its a MS-SQL database and i dont know how to list alle years in the columns and if there is more than one column with the same year it should only list the year once. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide more detail about your question, your table structure and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to extract years from dates.

```
Select DATEPART(year, date_col) from table
```

As for the multiple columns containing the date, you will need to do a CASE statement.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(year, col2) = DATEPART(year, col1) Then Something END
```

See DATEPART documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx